# Emcee won't run multithreaded in Windows

Tags: python, multithreading, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, emcee

I am having trouble running the python Emcee MCMC code in multithreaded mode on a Windows desktop. It runs fine with one thread, and runs in single or multithreaded mode on my Mac OSX laptop. Here is the simple example code (taken from the Emcee website example).

```
import numpy as np
 import emcee

def lnprob(x, ivar):
    return -0.5 * np.sum(ivar * x ** 2)

ndim, nwalkers = 10, 100
ivar = 1. / np.random.rand(ndim)
p0 = [np.random.rand(ndim) for i in range(nwalkers)]

sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, ndim, lnprob, args=[ivar], threads=2)
%time sampler.run_mcmc(p0, 10000)
```

If I set threads=1, it runs fine on both machines, taking about 5 seconds to run. If I set threads= 2, it runs fine on the Mac but hangs on the Windows machine. There are no errors noted in the notebook, but in the command prompt window, I see a jumbled mixture of error messages, as if two processes are trying to write error message at the same time. I can't seem to copy and paste them from the window, but they end up with:

```
"Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'lnprob'
```

On both machines, I am running this in a Jupyter notebook. I have checked that I have update versions of emcee, conda, and anaconda. Any ideas as to why I am having trouble?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, maybe this helps:

(from: [anaconda windows package and multithreading #381](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/381))

I can confirm that via the anaconda 2 and 3 packages on os x that the multithreading is not working correctly.

Building from source with anaconda 2 and 3 on OSX 10.11 doesn't work by default, but a bit of fiddling with the compiler options gets it going okay.

By default, homebrew will install gcc to be used with the versioned name, e.g. gcc-6. you can either add the lines

```
`os.environ["CC"] = "gcc-6"`    

`os.environ["CXX"] = "g++-6"`
```

to setup.py or call

```
`CC=gcc-6; python setup.py build; pip install -e`
```

to get it working correctly. this should be updated in the docs.

Comment: This doesn't really help, although I appreciate the response. My problem is with Windows, not OSX. The code runs fine in OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Using the proper idiom (`if __name__ == '__main__':`) in the main module will resolve it:

```
import numpy as np
import emcee

def lnprob(x, ivar):
    return -0.5 * np.sum(ivar * x ** 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ndim, nwalkers = 10, 100
    ivar = 1. / np.random.rand(ndim)
    p0 = [np.random.rand(ndim) for i in range(nwalkers)]

    sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, ndim, lnprob, args=[ivar], threads=2)
    sampler.run_mcmc(p0, 10000)
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue for me when running in a Jupyter notebook. One thread works fine, while more than one causes a hang.

Comment: Hi @kevinea, Yes, this was not tested in a Jupyter notebook. I recommend running it in an IDE such as PyCharm for now.